# Can't start Netty server in Spring Webflux 2.1.0.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, netty, spring-webflux, project-reactor

In my Java application I use Spring Webflux as dependency like:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

With version 2.0.6.RELEASE I could start Netty server with this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RouterFunction<?> route;
    route = route(GET("/hello"),
            request -> {
                Mono<String> hi = Mono.just("hi");
                return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(TEXT_PLAIN).body(hi, String.class);
            });
    HttpHandler httpHandler = RouterFunctions.toHttpHandler(route);
    ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter adapter =
            new ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter(httpHandler);
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create("localhost", 8080);
    server.startAndAwait(adapter);
}
```

but in 2.1.0 it doesn't compile. I also tried something like this, but still can't make it works.

```
    HttpServer
            .create()
            .host("localhost")
            .port(8080)
            .handle(adapter)
            .bind()
            .block();
```

How to start the Netty server?

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-httphandler
https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to manually start your server in a Spring Boot application, you can just declare your `RouterFunction` as `@Bean` like this:

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> hello() {
    return route(GET("/hello"),
            request -> {
                Mono<String> hi = Mono.just("hi");
                return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(TEXT_PLAIN).body(hi, String.class);
            });
}
```

Spring Boot is shielding you from the underlying API changes in the supported servers.

The main method here doesn't look like a typical Spring Boot main method, so I don't think you're actually using Spring Boot here. In any case, here's a code snippet that fixes your issue; since Reactor Netty 0.8, the `bind()` part is separated from the actual waiting part:

```
RouterFunction<?> route = RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/hello"),
                request -> {
                    Mono<String> hi = Mono.just("hi");
                    return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).body(hi, String.class);
                });
HttpHandler httpHandler = RouterFunctions.toHttpHandler(route);
ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter adapter =
        new ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter(httpHandler);
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create().host("localhost").port(8080);
DisposableServer disposableServer = server.handle(adapter).bind().block();
disposableServer.onDispose().block();
```